# python set package version from Tag while installing via pip

Tags: python, pip, package, git-tag

We're building a python package for our team with a structure similar to the following

```
pkg_dir
├── setup.py  # setup.py for package "pkg"
└── some_module.py
other_dir
└── some_file
some_other_file
```

And are using the following to install it via pip described [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git)

```
$ pip install -e "git+https://git.example.com/MyProject.git#egg=MyProject"
```

There's an option to install it from a Tag like so

```
$ pip install -e "git+https://git.example.com/MyProject.git@v1.0#egg=MyProject"
```

The package version is provided in the setup.py file as instructed [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-setup-py)

Now, My question is that is there a way to set the version at the time of installation taken directly from the tag name?
That way we won't have to manually change the version in the setup.py file, versioning would become as simple as just creating a new Tag.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not point to a branch then? You would move the tip of the branch to always point at the commit you want to deploy (the same commit as the one the tag points at). Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Management follows the convention of using Tags for releases, Branching isn't an option.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, and @phd might be right, you probably want `setuptools_scm` or something similar.

Comment: setuptools_scm did the trick, Thanks @phd